# CodedUI WPF Clear Cache?

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

I'm having an issue where my test seems to be caching a stale version of the control.

In my application, there is a grid on the screen with rows of data and customisable columns. The columns depends on which folder the user is in, and the user can click a folder to switch to. When switching, the grid refreshes and displays the new row data with the columns for that folder.

The issue appears when querying for the grid data. If I attempt to gather it before switching folder, then there is no problem - however, if the folder is switched and CodedUI is used to collect data from the grid, then it returns the data present on the original folder (i.e, if the first folder had 4 columns and the second had 7, then even when switching to the second, the query would return 4 columns...)

This happens despite me not intentionally finding the grid until I need to. Until the second folder is clicked, I do not instantiate a grid CodedUI object in the test. My assumption is that, when searching for other controls (such as the folders) CodedUI finds the grid and caches it.

My question is: is there a way to manually clear out the control cache and demand that it find the most up-to-date version of the grid? I have tried various solutions, such as the .Find() function, and enabling AlwaysSearch in the PlaybackSettings and the SearchConfigurations on the object, but none have so far worked...

(If it is worth mentioning, I am using the DevExpress WPF controls.)

Comment: Have you tried the VisibleOnly search configuration?

Comment: I have - sadly it has also made no difference. Any other suggestions?

Comment: What happens if you use FindMatchingControls instead of Find - does the expected grid show up in the returned collection?

Comment: Also, what happens if you run the query for the first time *after* switching to the 2nd grid? If you get the same result we can rule out cache staleness as the cause.

Comment: If I run FindMatchingControls - only one grid is returned. The scenario you suggested is actually how I'm running the test - I don't actually query for the grid until the second one is shown. The original grid is never requested.

Comment: Perhaps the builder was used against the original grid, and the UIMap has some search properties that are unique to that grid? Perhaps you could try using the builder against your grid post switch, just to see if that gives different results?

Comment: I've tried - with interesting results. If I use the test builder before changing folders, on the original grid, it can find the various components and highlights them blue without much difficulty. If I then change to a new grid, then the builder seems unable to find the new grid, and won't highlight any of the components when I mouse over them

Comment: If the builder isn't finding the controls, that sounds like bad news - this suggests to me that CodedUi can't deal with that particular grid at all :(